# Concealing a CSS file with JS - how?

Tags: javascript, css

I accidentally found a webpage that employs a technique of hiding the stylesheet file, serving it via a JS instead.

Even when I open the page in Chrome DevTools, I cannot find a link to a CSS file, and when I inspect the JS that goes with the page, the only reference to a CSS I can find, reads:

```
n("../../node_modules/react-intl-tel-input/dist/main.css");
```

The app.js file though, that contains this reference, is located in the root folder of the website, and that would mean the css file is effectively located ABOVE the root folder, which makes it inaccessible.

How is this possible, and what's this technique of concealing the stylesheet called? Is the CSS file really inaccessible?

The page in question is:

https://login.blockchain.com/#/login

Comment: You still need to make the http request for it and you found it so not really hidden. :)

Comment: css can live anywhere; above, below, aside, under...

Comment: There is no way (zero) to conceal code that is delivered to the browser. That is the nature of client-side code.

Comment: I haven't found the actual CSS file. I cannot access it. How is its contents then served to the browser?

Comment: the css file is embedded in the javascript file. The path to the file was used as a key that can be used to find it within whatever structure it is stored.

Comment: It doesn't seem that way - when I search for random classes from the html of the page, none of them are in the text of the JS file.

Comment: Very well could be obfuscated or even inlined.

Comment: I guess the fronted dev tools are doing this, the path you see is its location on the dev environment.

Answer (score 1):

The page in question uses `webpack` so in my opinion there is separate `css` file but while they are building the production code the opted out to create separate css chunk file. So you can see the `css` in html file.

[image]

Comment: What does that mean, exactly? What's a CSS chunk file? And the CSS in the html is not the main CSS for the page.